# How to configure default email system in magento 2.3.4

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, email

In my case, I can't send any email the default email system also no working. For checking, I sent the order confirmation mail it is not sending. it shows the error alert **"Unable to send mail: Unknown error"**

I had enabled all features but it is not working.

**Sales:**

```
Check Stores->Configuration-> Sales->Sales Emails->Order . Enabled is "Yes".
```

**Email Communication:**

```
Check Stores->Configuration-> Advanced->System->Mail Sending Settings. Email Communication is enabled.
```

Comment: Please check the your sever mail service is enable ??

Comment: You need to setup email server configuration in order for E-mails to work.

Comment: check error log in magento. to get more info about error